# How to make a flexbox container work for multiple elements, but only one is visible

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container which can contain several buttons (feasibly up to 3).

I have used flexbox to make my desired layout. In this layout, all buttons are rendered in a line and `space-evenly` is used to give space between each item. E.g:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  
  width: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

button {
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portalContainer">
    <button>Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Due to how my HTML is set up, one of the buttons is **wrapped in a div**. This div is **always rendered** even when it does not have content (a button) to go inside it. The reason for this is because this div is the target for a **React portal**.

In a situation where I do not wish to render *Button 1* I still require the wrapping div `portalContainer` to exist. I cannot get around this.

The issue therefore arises where the `portalContainer` has no content (no button was rendered into it) but *Button 2* renders off to the side. This is due to flexbox still attempting to space the elements evenly, even when one element has nothing inside it. Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  
  width: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

button {
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portalContainer"></div>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

How can I make the solo instance of *Button 2* show in the centre of the wrapper, even though `portalContainer` is still in the DOM?

I looked into the possibility of setting `portalContainer` as `display: none;` and then using something like `:has(button)` to unset that style when the container has a button inside. However `:has()` does not have Firefox support.

Is there a way of doing this? I cannot apply any logic to rendering the `portalContainer` - it must always be there.

Full example here in Codepen: https://codepen.io/asos-francesca/pen/qBQKPOX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` pseudo-selector instead, which has greater browser support:

https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Aempty

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

button {
  height: 75px;
}

#portalContainer:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portalContainer"></div>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I knew there would be a CSS solution somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to set the `display:none` to `portalContainer` only if the conainer doesn't have any childrens.
The next code snippet resolved the problem on CodePen.

```js
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll("#portalContainer").forEach((element) => { if (!element.hasChildNodes()) element.style.display = "none" })
</script>
```

Keep in mind that id's must be unique in html!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not want to add any JS if I can do this with just CSS, which it appears I can.